# AngularJS-JQuery : How can I make elements of a dynamic list draggable?

Tags: angularjs, jquery-ui

In my app I have a dynamic list of devices `vm.deviceNames` that is generated by my controller  so in my HTML code I made `ng-repeat="device in vm.deviceNames` to make a list of my devices then I wanted to make them draggable with JQuery but it didn't work for me and when I tried with a pre-defined list and I ran the App it worked !! I tried with `$window.load()` but it didn't work neither, how can I make it work for my generated list. Here is my code

```html
<ion-view>
<script>
  $( window ).load( function() {
    console.log("window is loaded");
    $( ".device-list-item" ).draggable();
    $( "#container" ).droppable({
        drop: function (event, ui) {
            var $canvas = $(this);
            if (!ui.draggable.hasClass('canvas-element')) {
                    var $canvasElement = ui.draggable.clone();
                    $canvasElement.addClass('canvas-element');
                    $canvasElement.draggable({
                      containment: '#container'
                    });
                    $canvas.append($canvasElement);
                    $canvasElement.css({
                        left: (ui.position.left),
                        top: (ui.position.top),
                        position: 'absolute'
                  });
            }
        }
    });
  });
  </script>
  <ion-content
    has-bouncing="true"
    padding="true"
    scroll="true">
    
    <div ng-if="vm.deviceNames.length">
      <div class="heading" ng-bind="('TEXT_HOISTINGDEVICES' | translate)"></div>
      <div class="description" ng-bind="('DASHBOARD_DESCRIPTION' | translate)"></div>      
      
      <ul class="column-device-list" >
      
        <div id="{{device.id}}" class="device-list-item" ng-repeat="device in vm.deviceNames">
          <div ng-click="vm.removeBase(device.id)"><i class="se-icon-close"></i></div>          
          <div class="button icon-left button-clear" ng-dbclick="deviceSelected(device.id)" 
              ui-sref="app.dashboard.details({transmitterId: device.id, transmitterName: device.uiName})">
              <div class="dashboard-device-container">
                <div class="icons"><i class="device-icon"></i></div>
                <div class="deviceid" ng-bind="device.id"></div>
                <div class="icons" ng-if="device.uiShowError"><i class="exlhoist-alarm-error-icon"></i></div>
              </div>              
          </div>
        </div>
      
      </ul>
    </div>
    </ion-content> 

</ion-view>
```

Comment: This is not a good practice to manipulate the DOM outside of angularjs context. You can't guarantee that this code `$( ".device-list-item" ).draggable();` will run when all the items will be rendered by `ng-repeat` directive. It is better to write a directive for this purpose or use one of existing one like [angular-dragdrop](https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop).

Comment: I would suggest finding an Angular wrapper for the jquery-ui component you need, for example https://github.com/codef0rmer/angular-dragdrop, or follow a tutorial to write one http://www.erol.si/2014/07/ng-repeat-with-draggable-or-how-to-correctly-use-angularjs-with-jquery-ui/

Comment: Thank you. I used directives and the drag is working well but the drop is not working here is the droppable <div>tag `<div id="container" data-drop="true" data-jqyoui-options="{accept:'.device-list-item'}" jqyoui-droppable class="drop_container"></div>` where the device-list-item is the class of the draggables